# Driving Style Detection using Smartphone Sensors

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, inertial-navigation

I want to measure the acceleration (forward and lateral separately) using an android smartphone device in order to be able to analyse the driving behavior/style.

My approach would be as follows:

### 1. Aligning coordinate systems

**Calibration (no motion / first motion):**
While the car is stationary, I would calculate the magnitude of gravity using `Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY` and rotate it straight to the z-axis (pointing downwards assuming a flat surface). That way, the **pitch** and **roll** angles should be near zero and equal to the angles of the car relativ to the world.

After this, I would start moving straight forward with the car to get a first motion indication using `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and rotate this magnitude straight to the x-axis (pointing forward). This way, the **yaw** angle should be equal to the vehicle's heading relativ to the world.

**Update Orientation (while driving):**
To be able to keep the coordinate systems aligned while driving I am going to use `Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY` to maintain the roll and pitch of the system via

[image]

[image]

where A_x,y,z is the acceleration of gravity.

Usually, the yaw angle would be maintained via `Sensor.ROTATION_VECTOR` or `Sensor.MAGNETIC_FIELD`. However, the reason behind not using them is because I am going to use the application also in **electrical vehicles**. The high amounts of volts and ampere produced by the engine would presumably make the accuracy of those sensor values suffer. Hence, the best alternative that I know (although not optimal) is using the GPS course to maintain the yaw angle.

### 2. Getting measurements

By applying all aforementioned rotations it should be possible to maintain an alignment between the smartphone's and vehicle's coordinate systems and, hence, giving me the pure forward and lateral acceleration values on the x-axis and y-axis.

### *Questions:*

- Is this approach applicable or did I miss something crucial?
- Is there an easier/alternative approach to this?

Comment: I changed the title to let people know exactly what I want to archive and hopefully get some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to finding acceleration, if you have access to the source code of the GPS couldn't you find the forward motion by calculating the distance/time from the GPS?

If the goal is to find driving behavior and style I would imagine gathering a large data set and then using a k means cluster algorithm to sort the data followed by an lstmRNN (to make predictions) could be another method. (Though this requires you to have data from a large set I don't know if this is possible nor do am I aware of what factors you would want to incorporate in your data set).

Sounds like an interesting problem though.